# AND - OR in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My code as :

```
Select 
    ProductId, ProductCode, Color
From 
    dbo.Product 
Where 
   @Productname = ProductName 
   and ( Color != 'Orange' or Color != 'Green')
```

And result includes product with color 'Orange', 'Green' :

```
    1   prod0001   Orange
    2   prod0002   Blue
    3   prod0003   Yellow
    4   prod0004   Green
    5   prod0005   Orange
    6   prod0006   Blue
    7   prod0007   Yellow
    8   prod0008   Green
```

I want  to get product with color != green or != orange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `and`, not `or`.  But, this is more easily written using `not in`:

```
Select ProductId, ProductCode, Color
From dbo.Product
Where @Productname = ProductName and 
      Color not in ('Orange', 'Green') ;
```

Your logic is:

```
(color <> 'Orange') or (color <> 'Green')
```

Well, this is always true.  If color is `Orange`, then the first clause is false, but the second is true:  false or true is true.  However, `not in` is simpler to write and clearer than just replacing the `or` with `and`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean is color !=green or !=orange?

```
Color NOT IN ('green', 'orange')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'not in' or 'and' , like that

Select ProductId,ProductCode,Color
From dbo.Product where Color not in ('Orange','Green');

Select ProductId,ProductCode,Color
From dbo.Product where Color <> 'Orange' and Color <> 'Green'

Or will not work, it would be illogical, because a register that is green is not orange and a register that is orange is not green. because of that it get the both.

Comment: @Hugo Jose make sure you put your code in code blocks by highlighting it and pressing Ctrl + k